# Media keeps pausing randomly MacOS High Sierra. Spotify/iTunes/Quicktime

Tags: itunes, high-sierra, mediaplayer, spotify

I'm on a mid-2012 MBP and I've started having this issue since upgrading to High Sierra. Sometimes it'll pause the media and start back on its own or sometimes it'll just stop it completely and I'll have to physically unpause the media.

I wondered if there was some kind of phantom media control issues with High Sierra or if anyone else has seen something similar. All of my Google-fu only pulls up people having trouble with media controls trying to do everything.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107606/discussion-on-question-by-alex-perham-media-keeps-pausing-randomly-macos-high-si).